# Visual Studio compiling with Boost

Tags: c++, boost, visual-studio-2012

I've been trying to compile some code including some Boost classes using Visual Studio 2012, and I'm consistently receiving an error about multiple declarations.

```
1>c:\boost\boost_1_53_0\boost\tr1\memory.hpp(43): error C2874: using-declaration causes a multiple declaration of 'boost::bad_weak_ptr'
```

This happens with several other Boost classes that are being included from boost\tr1\memory.hpp.

I've checked to see if the additional include directories and library directories are in place, and as far as I can tell they are, but the issue persists. Anyone have any idea? Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps you are doing stuff like "using namespace std" while doing something similar with Boost namespaces. Please note that the [`<memory>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/memory) header exposes a [`bad_weak_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/bad_weak_ptr) as well.

Comment: As far as I can tell, I'm not using any namespaces for my code minus the main file.

Comment: Same issue here. I have a using namespace boost directive. I get it that it is also defined in the memory header, but I don't get the difference between vc10 and 11. The vc11 version has the line using _STD shared_ptr. I 'solved' my problem by removing the boost::memory include. Could someone please elaborate on this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that shared_ptr is part of std **and** std::tr1 in C++11. Since VS2012 is (mostly) C++11 compliant, there seems to be a namespace collision between boost\tr1\memory.hpp and the memory header.

I think it could really be related to a using directive, as pointed out by Mihai Todor. In my case I could remove the boost memory.hpp include.